# C programming - Process terminated with status -1073741510

Tags: c, windows

If I run my code when the const N is higher than a specific value (like 30,000 or more), I get "Process terminated with status -1073741510" and the values in my result.dat are not what it supposed to be.

I've tried to look up possible solutions, I know it's a stack overflow problem, but I can't find out anything about what should I modify in my code in order to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>


#define N 5000
//static int nep[N];

int main()
{


    srand(time(NULL));
    int nap=365, szam=0,ember;
    float beta=0.3,gamma=0.7,delta=0.05,valseg;
    int dbErzekeny,dbBeteg,dbGyogyult;


    int *nep;
    nep = (int*) malloc(N * sizeof(int));

    if(nep == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error! memory not allocated.");
        exit(0);
    }

    //nep = malloc(N * sizeof(char));
    int i,j;

    FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen("eredmeny.dat", "w");



    dbErzekeny=N-1;dbBeteg=1;dbGyogyult=0;
    nep[0]=1;
    for(i=1;i<N;i++){
        nep[i]=0;
    }

    for(i=1; i<=nap; i++){
        for(j=0;j<N;j++){
            szam=(rand()%N);
            if(nep[szam]==0){
                ember=(rand() % N);
                if(nep[ember]==1){
                    valseg=(rand() % 100);
                    valseg=valseg/100;
                    if(valseg <=gamma){
                        nep[szam]=1;
                        dbErzekeny=dbErzekeny-1;dbBeteg=dbBeteg+1;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(nep[szam]==1){
                valseg=(rand() % 100);
                valseg = valseg/100;
                if(valseg<= beta){
                    nep[szam]=2;
                    dbBeteg=dbBeteg-1;dbGyogyult=dbGyogyult+1;
                }
            }
            if(nep[szam]==2){
                valseg=(rand() % 100);
                valseg = valseg/100;
                if(valseg <= delta){
                    nep[szam]=1;
                    dbBeteg=dbBeteg+1;dbGyogyult=dbGyogyult-1;
                }
            }
        }
        if(fp!=NULL){
            fprintf(fp,"%d; %d; %d; %d; \n",i,dbErzekeny,dbBeteg,dbGyogyult);
        }else{
            printf("Error!");
        }

    }
    free(nep);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(nep[szam]==2 && 1){` is the same as `if(nep[szam]==2){`

Comment: check the result of `fp = fopen("result.dat", "w");` fp must not be NULL

Comment: use a real dynamic allocation with `malloc`: `static int *nep;` then `nep = malloc(N * sizeof(int))`

Comment: also `rand()` has a range that may be below `N` which makes your results incorrect

Comment: rand()%N-1 might be equal to -1, which would read or write out of bounds on the array.

Comment: Tried these guys, still not working, it's not because of the fp null nullcheck, also not the rand out of range part.

Also malloc doesn't seem to solve the issue

Comment: @AranySandor `Tried these` Then update the question with the new code, otherwise we can't guess what you are actually running.

Comment: It is updated. //

Comment: @AranySandor Cannot duplicate the error with your updated code. Tried a few runs with `N` over 100,000 and they all completed fine with exit code `0`. The only way to get `-1073741510` was to break execution with Ctrl-C, which is to be expected since 0xC000013A is [`STATUS_CONTROL_C_EXIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/596a1078-e883-4972-9bbc-49e60bebca55).